# When does React call a component constructor function and what's like the execution flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say I have a simple component like this one:

```js
export default function Foo({someProp}) {
  const a = Math.random();

  return <div>{a}{someProp}</div>
}
```

As far as I know, when `someProp` updates, React will trigger a re-render. Will it execute the whole `Foo` function once again and reassign `const a` a new random value? Will the value be displayed in the `<div>`?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you test it out?

Comment: Just didn't have the opportunity at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for every one of your question is **yes**. A re-render is triggered when there is a `props` change as you said, and also when there is a `state` change. When re-rendering and also on the first render, everything behaves like in a normal JavaScript function, as far as assigning variables and everything else, except for some things related to React Hooks, like a `state` made with `useState`, a `ref` made with `useRef`...